# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

**В предложении: "Да здравствуют музы!"  - "да" - это усил. частица?**

Answer (score 2):

Вас интересуют знаки в конструкции "В предложении: "Да здравствуют музы!" - "да" - это усил. частица?" Такой вариант знаков верен, я думаю. Если убрать двоеточие и тире, обрамляющие конструкцию "Да здравствуют музы!" то получится нагромождение, стык закрывающих и открывающих кавычек, что нежелательно.

Comment: Меня смущает сокращение "усил.". Вряд ли это часть "предложения"...

Comment: Ой, не знаю! Знаю только, что она не "усил.", а формообразующая.

Comment: А детей этому уже учат?  
Я бы согдласился, но мне как-то непривычно считать "да здравствует!" повелительным наклонением.    
А "пусть будет" тогда какое? Уступительное?    
Не, что-то перемудрили дяди с этими формообразующими частицами...

Comment: Екатерина права, частица "Да" - формообразующая частица. Сказать, что детей этому учат - не могу. Скорее упоминаем при изучении повелительного наклонения, при изучении частиц. Такие предложения достаточно редки, поэтому информация забывается. Вспоминаем потом перед ЕГЭ.

Comment: Я не спорил по сути того, что она формообразующая, ибо не с чем, вопрос терминологии, а это все рауно что о вкусах спорить.
 
Просто если признать "да здравствует" повелительным наклонением (иначе разговор о том, что частица именно формообразующая,  бессмысленен), то чем будет "пусть здравствует", "пусть будет", каким наклонением? По логике "пусть" здесь несет уступительно значение, а вся грамматика точно соответвует рассматриваемой конструкции с "да".

Comment: Тоже повелительное наклонение.

Comment: Ну что тут поделать...
Бедные дети, у меня бы мозг взорвался, если бы классе в пятом мне такое сказали. Уступка, разрешение - у вдруг **повелительное** наклонение. Но в наше время как-то по-другому учили...

Comment: У Ефремовой:Пусть - частица, употр. при образовании форм повелительного наклонения глагола, обозначая: 1) побуждение, приказание, долженствование; 2) дозволение, допущение, согласие; 3) пожелание, призыв. 2. Употр. при выражении пожелания, просьбы (в сочетании с частицей: бы). 3. Употр. при выражении готовности, стремления к чему-л., пожелания себе чего-л. 4. Употр. при выражении уступки, согласия с чем-л.; соответствует по значению сл.: хорошо, ладно, так и быть. 5. Употр. при выражении уступительного допущения; соответствует по значению сл.: хотя бы даже, хоть и.

Answer (score 0):

Да, частица.

А в чем сомнения? Спрашиваю только потому, что системе ответ показался слишком коротким.

Comment: Обратите внимание, Маэстро, на формулировку вопроса крупным синим шрифтом. Мы с Виктором тоже попались...))) Забавная ситуация...

Comment: Я перестал читать написанное синим после того как наши уважаемые модеры стали ругаться, кто главнее по части правкт заголовков.